# How to remove search box from c:PageBlockTableEnhancerADV

Tags: apex

Is they anyway to remove the searchbox from the c:PageBlockTableEnhancerADV?

Thanks

Comment: Hmmm. II'll accept your decision but this is odd to me. I am using c:PageBlockTableEnhancerADV in my apex code for a vf page. It works fine but I just want to remove the search box. Why is this different if I had asked if one can remove the searchbox on a standard SF page? Is not not specific enough? There's no code to display either I can or I can not. Oh SF gurus why is this off topic?

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible (like almost everything that is built with HTML and JavaScript), but you will have to edit the component code to do this. There is no easy way to remove the searchbox as far as I know, from **[looking into it's code](https://github.com/Avinava/PageBlockTableEnhancerADV/)**.

You can also create an Issue in this repository to make the searchbox optional, in a way that you can set an attribute like `enableSearchBox="false"`.